# How to use HTTP.sys to host Blazor app (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I'm developing a web app using Blazor with .NET 6.0.11 . Building the application produces a `.exe` file that runs Kestrel. How do I change this to HTTP.sys?

When I google for this topic most of the results are from older versions of ASP.NET where code like `var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseWebListener(` ... goes inside `Main()`. But Blazor .NET 6 projects have a different structure, there is no `Main()` and no `WebHostBuilder`.

[The only relevant tutorial I could find](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-net-core-launchsettings-json-file/) covers excellently how to configure either IIS or Kestrel from `launchSettings.json` but says nothing about HTTP.sys.

My `launchSettings.json` (which launches as Kestrel) looks like:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:10563",
      "sslPort": 44364
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "MyAppName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:10555",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:10555",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and `Program.cs` looks like:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

// [omitted other services added for my app]    

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

The `Program.cs` doesn't mention anything about json files nor Kestrel, I'm not sure how it actually ends up reading `appsettings.json` eventually and deciding to use Kestrel.

Background: I created this project initially by following the reference application at learn.microsoft.com .

Answer (score 1):

An answer was found in passing under [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0).

No changes required to `launchSettings.json` or `appSettings.json`; and the following code should be added to `Program.cs` , before the statement `var app = builder.Build();`, obviously:

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    builder.WebHost.UseHttpSys(options =>
    {
        // set options here if desired
    });
}
```